# Return an object from a function that has nested ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I would like to write a javascript function that returns informations from youtube videos; to be more specific I would like to get the ID and the length of videos got by a search, in a json object. So I took a look at the youtube API and I came out with this solution:

```
   function getYoutubeDurationMap( query ){
        var youtubeSearchReq = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+ query +
                "&max-results=20&duration=long&category=film&alt=json&v=2";
        var youtubeMap = [];
        $.getJSON(youtubeSearchReq, function(youtubeResult){
            var youtubeVideoDetailReq = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
            for(var i =0;i<youtubeResult.feed.entry.length;i++){
                var youtubeVideoId = youtubeResult.feed.entry[i].id.$t.substring(27);
                $.getJSON(youtubeVideoDetailReq + youtubeVideoId + "?alt=json&v=2",function(videoDetails){
                    youtubeMap.push({id: videoDetails.entry.id.$t.substring(27),runtime: videoDetails.entry.media$group.media$content[0].duration});

                });
            }
        });
        return youtubeMap;    

    }
```

The logic is ok, but as many of you have already understood because of ajax when I call this function I get an empty array. Is there anyway to get the complete object? Should I use a Deferred object? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: No, you should make a synchronous request.

But just don't do that: learn to use the asynchronous logic of Javascript, and you'll be fine with a lot of other things too.

Comment: Execute things on callback...

Comment: yes, you should use deferred objects.

Comment: For more background: https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use deferred objects.

The simplest approach here is to create an array into which you can store the `jqXHR` result of your inner `$.getJSON()` calls.

```
var def = [];
for (var i = 0; ...) {
    def[i] = $.getJSON(...).done(function(videoDetails) {
        ... // extract and store in youtubeMap
    });
}
```

and then at the end of the whole function, use `$.when` to create a new promise that will be resolved only when *all* of the inner calls have finished:

```
return $.when.apply($, def).then(function() {
    return youtubeMap;
});
```

and *then* use `.done` to handle the result from your function:

```
getYoutubeDurationMap(query).done(function(map) {
    // map contains your results
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/8XQ4H/ for a demonstration using this YouTube API of how deferred objects allow you to completely separate the AJAX calls from the subsequent data processing for your "duration search".

The code is a little long, but reproduced here too.  However whilst the code is longer than you might expect note that the generic functions herein are now reusable for *any* calls you might want to make to the YouTube API.

```
// generic search - some of the fields could be parameterised
function youtubeSearch(query) {
    var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos';
    return $.getJSON(url, {
        q: query,
        'max-results': 20,
        duration: 'long', category: 'film',  // parameters?
        alt: 'json', v: 2
    });
}

// get details for one YouTube vid
function youtubeDetails(id) {
    var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + id;
    return $.getJSON(url, {
        alt: 'json', v: 2
    });
}

// get the details for *all* the vids returned by a search
function youtubeResultDetails(result) {
    var details = [];

    var def = result.feed.entry.map(function(entry, i) {
        var id = entry.id.$t.substring(27);
        return youtubeDetails(id).done(function(data) {
            details[i] = data;
        });
    });

    return $.when.apply($, def).then(function() {
        return details;
    });
}

// use deferred composition to do a search and then get all details
function youtubeSearchDetails(query) {
   return youtubeSearch(query).then(youtubeResultDetails);
}

// this code (and _only_ this code) specific to your requirement to
// return an array of {id, duration}
function youtubeDetailsToDurationMap(details) {
    return details.map(function(detail) {
        return {
            id: detail.entry.id.$t.substring(27),
            duration: detail.entry.media$group.media$content[0].duration
        }
    });
}

// and calling it all together
youtubeSearchDetails("after earth").then(youtubeDetailsToDurationMap).done(function(map) {
    // use map[i].id and .duration
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, you can't return `youtubeMap` directly as it's not yet populated at the point of return. But you can return a *Promise* of a fully populated `youtubeMap`, which can be acted on with eg `.done(), .fail()` or `.then()`.

```
function getYoutubeDurationMap(query) {
    var youtubeSearchReq = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=" + query + "&max-results=20&duration=long&category=film&alt=json&v=2";
    var youtubeVideoDetailReq = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
    var youtubeMap = [];
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    var p = $.getJSON(youtubeSearchReq).done(function(youtubeResult) {
        $.each(youtubeResult.feed.entry, function(i, entry) {
            var youtubeVideoId = entry.id.$t.substring(27);
            //Build a .then() chain to perform sequential queries
            p = p.then(function() {
                return $.getJSON(youtubeVideoDetailReq + youtubeVideoId + "?alt=json&v=2").done(function(videoDetails) {
                    youtubeMap.push({
                        id: videoDetails.entry.id.$t.substring(27),
                        runtime: videoDetails.entry.media$group.media$content[0].duration
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        //Add a terminal .then() to resolve dfrd when all video queries are complete.
        p.then(function() {
            dfrd.resolve(query, youtubeMap);
        });
    });
    return dfrd.promise();
}
```

And the call to `getYoutubeDurationMap()` would be of the following form :

```
getYoutubeDurationMap("....").done(function(query, map) {
    alert("Query: " + query + "\nYouTube videos found: " + map.length);
});
```

Notes:

- In practice, you would probably loop through `map` and display the `.id` and `.runtime` data.
- Sequential queries is preferable to parallel queries as sequential is kinder to both client and server, and more likely to succeed.
- Another valid approach would be to return an array of separate promises (one per video) and to respond to completion with `$.when.apply(..)`, however the required data would be more awkward to extract.

Comment: nice, but in my experience running the queries in series will make the batch slower than it could be, and the browser _should_ limit the number of concurrent AJAX queries to 4 or so if they're run in parallel.

Comment: Yes, it will run slower but is more guaranteed to complete. I've not done a comprehensive review of browser behaviour in this regard but wouldn't steak my life on all of them imposing a safeguard. Remember there's a bunch of popular "also rans" out there these days especially in Linux-land (incl Raspberry PI) - Midori, Dillo, Chromium, NetSurf, IceWeasel ... . How do they behave? I haven't got a clue.